# COMException when running a Background UWP on Windows 10 IOT

Tags: c#, windows, raspberry-pi, iot, i2c

I am developing an I2C solution for a Raspberry Pi and Teensy 3.6 Arduino . The Pi is going to send NTP via I2C to the Arduino. I have done research for weeks, and tried to test the code below, and receive a couple errors.

```
public sealed class StartupTask : IBackgroundTask
{
    public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Wait(5000);
            try
            {
                await I2C();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // eats fast inputs
            }
        }
    }

    private async void Wait(int millis)
    {
        await Task.Delay(millis);
    }

    private async Task I2C()
    {
        var settings = new I2cConnectionSettings(1);
        settings.BusSpeed = I2cBusSpeed.FastMode;
        var controller = await I2cController.GetDefaultAsync();

        using (I2cDevice device = controller.GetDevice(settings))
        {
            byte[] writeBuf = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 };
            device.Write(writeBuf);
        }
    }
}
```

Using the debug console, I have found that the I2C method never goes all the way through the using statement.

EXCEPTIONS:

Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in i2cTestIOT.winmd
WinRT information: Unexpected number of bytes was transferred. Expected: '. Actual: '.
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
WinRT information: Unexpected number of bytes was transferred. Expected: '. Actual: '.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this error with Raspberry pi and Arduino Uno using exact your code.(If it is a complete reproducible code). So

> Using the debug console, I have found that the I2C method never goes
>   all the way through the using statement.

Make sure the `1` is the right I2C address for your Teensy 3.6 Arduino and check the SDA and SCL connect correctly. Refer to [Windows IoT Core pin mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/pinmappings/pinmappingsrpi).

Add `deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();` if you want the [background application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/backgroundapplications#how-are-background-applications-used) always running. Otherwise when the Run method ends, the background application ends.

```
private BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral;
public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

    //
    // TODO: Insert code to start one or more asynchronous methods
    //
}
```

Try the StandardMode speed first then FastMode later.

Comment: Hi Rita, thanks for the reply. 

For the address, I am using the i2c_t3 library, and I have tried a couple different addresses, currently I am using this line of code for the Arduino to start i2c:
`Wire.begin(I2C_SLAVE, 1, I2C_PINS_18_19, I2C_PULLUP_EXT, 400000);`

Comment: Also, I used the deferral line and now I get a new error.

`sending i2c data
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in i2cTestIOT.winmd
WinRT information: Slave address was not acknowledged.
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
WinRT information: Slave address was not acknowledged.`

I have connected pin 3(pi) to pin 18(teensy) and pin 5(pi) to pin 19(teensy). I am not sure if I need to connect the Vout and Vin to each board. 

https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_Wire.html

Comment: @Jared Connect the GND of two board together and show your Arduino side code.

Comment: I gave up on using I2C, I just decided to use UART and it works perfectly. Thanks for your help otherwise :)